# swift2, synchronise two functions in time, called from two place

Tags: swift, swift2, wifi

Im using this tutorial for connect two devices via wifi: https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-multipeer-connectivity/

I want to synchronise it in time. Im trying with clock but I think this is a wrong way.

Maybe you have some ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "synchronise it in time"?

Comment: Run func at the same moment on both devices

Comment: To my mind, you can do it only using some kind of timer. But is't it overkill? Why finally do you need synchronisation?

Comment: For smoother operations only.. I Did not Know It Would Be This Hard